# Three.js SubdivisionModifier "computeEdgeFaces" error

Tags: three.js

I'm doing a project with SubdivisionModifier but i got this error in firefox console:

"TypeError: computeEdgeFaces is not a function"

How can i fix it?

Here my create scene code:

```
   function createScene(geometry, scale, material) {

     var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier(3);

     geometry.mergeVertices();
     geometry.computeCentroids();
     geometry.computeFaceNormals();
     geometry.computeVertexNormals();

     modifier.modify(geometry);

     mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

     mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = scale;

     scene.add(mesh);
   }
```

This is the whole code: http://jsfiddle.net/user972611/yYRP5/

Thanks.

Three.js R64

Comment: FYI, `SubdivisionModifier` stopped working properly when three.js stopped supporting quad faces. I'd avoid it -- unless you want to fix it. three.js r.64

Comment: Thanks, so sad when hear it because this subdivision is very useful with me, hope someone can fix it to working properly back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HA, I got it's work with this code:

```
   function createScene( geometry, scale, material ) {

    geometry.mergeVertices();

    var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier(2);
        modifier.modify(geometry); 

    geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    geometry.computeTangents();

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```